# WMI Does not send Printed Job status with C#

Tags: c#, printing, wmi

I'm using WMI to get Print-Job statuses using WMI with C# code.
now, I'm getting all the [different statuses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394370(v=vs.85).aspx) from the printer **beside printed** which is very important for me to know when the job was finished printing the job.

now, I managed to get printed status but only if the **Keep printed Documents** (see attachment) property is on. but all the jobs are staying in the queue of the printer and I don't want that.

is there any way to get printed status from the printer without marking the Keep printed Documents property is on

[Printer Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiDKw.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood. You need a timer like `DispatcherTimer` to set an interval for the request. In the `Tick` you can check if the status of the printer is changed. Is that what you want?

Comment: no... i'm trying to get a "printed" status from the printer using WMI

Comment: Ok, but do you need to do the WMI request continuously? Do you know how to get `printed` status using WMI?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this piece of code to set the `KeepPrintedJobs` property to `true`.

```
string searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer";
ManagementObjectSearcher searchPrinters = new 
ManagementObjectSearcher(searchQuery);
ManagementObjectCollection printerCollection = searchPrinters.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject printer in printerCollection)
{
    PropertyDataCollection printerProperties = printer.Properties;
    foreach (PropertyData property in printerProperties)
    {
        if (property.Name == "KeepPrintedJobs")
        {
            printerProperties[property.Name].Value = true;
        }
    }
    printer.Put();
}
```